# What is the SQL Server system table that contains information about stored procedure parameters?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

What is the SQL Server system table that contains information about stored procedure parameters with  it's information like datatype, name, lenght, null or not?

thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can query sys.procedures and sys.parameters...

```
select pr.name, p.*
from sys.procedures pr 
inner join sys.parameters p on pr.object_id = p.object_id
```

And join to types too...

```
select pr.name, p.*, t.name, t.max_length
from sys.procedures pr 
inner join sys.parameters p on pr.object_id = p.object_id
inner join sys.types t on p.system_type_id = t.system_type_id
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also use

```
select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARAMETERS
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use

```
select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES \G;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    p.name AS [SP Name], qs.execution_count,
    ISNULL(qs.execution_count/DATEDIFF(Second, qs.cached_time, GETDATE()), 0) AS [Calls/Second],
    qs.total_worker_time/qs.execution_count AS [AvgWorkerTime], qs.total_worker_time AS [TotalWorkerTime],  
    qs.total_elapsed_time, qs.total_elapsed_time/qs.execution_count AS [avg_elapsed_time],
    qs.cached_time,
    isr.ROUTINE_DEFINITION
FROM sys.procedures AS p
INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats AS qs
ON p.[object_id] = qs.[object_id]
Inner Join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES as ISR
on p.name = isr.SPECIFIC_NAME
WHERE qs.database_id = DB_ID()
    and
    isr.ROUTINE_DEFINITION like '%XXXX%'  -- name of something you are looking for in the stored procedure

ORDER BY qs.execution_count DESC OPTION (RECOMPILE);
```

Comment: Please [edit] with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are [discouraged](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196187), because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

For those using SQL 2000

```
SELECT * FROM [dbName]..sysobjects  WHERE xtype = 'P'
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM [dbName]..sysComments
```

Join them by id

Answer (score 0):

This shows information about stored procedures and user-defined functions. It will include procedures/scalar functions without parameters, but will include parameter information if available.

```
SELECT 
O.Name ProcedureName, 
P.parameter_id Position,
P.Name ParameterName, 
P.max_length MaxLen, 
P.is_output IsOutput, 
P.has_default_value HasDefaultValue, 
P.default_value DefaultValue, 
P.is_nullable IsNullable, 
T.name TypeName, 
T.max_length TypeMaxLen,
O.type_desc TypeDescription
FROM SYS.OBJECTS O
LEFT JOIN SYS.PARAMETERS P ON O.object_id = P.object_id
LEFT JOIN SYS.TYPES T ON P.system_type_id = T.system_type_id
WHERE type_desc LIKE 'SQL_%'
ORDER BY O.Name, P.parameter_id, P.Name
```