# Restore stored procedure from corrupt database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, corruption

I'm working on trying to salvage as much as possible from a corrupt database. I can query tables, but not see their metadata (properties, script as...) - all those actions result in

> The Table ... does not exist on the server

errors when it clearly does, since `Select * from ...` works.

I was able to create a new database and get both schema and data by doing:

```
select * 
into newdB.dbo.table 
from corruptdb.dbo.table
```

WHEW!

Now on to stored procedures. I can execute them, but I can't modify or script as. Any suggestions as to how to save those??

Thanks

Comment: Try looking at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10451146/what-is-the-sql-server-system-table-that-contains-information-about-stored-proce

Comment: SELECT definition FROM sys.sql_modules...

Comment: This! Everything else fails, but this saved the day. Thank you Aaron Bertrand.

Answer (score 0):

Try `sp_helptext` to see if you can get the source of the stored procedure back.

(see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176112.aspx).

If that doesn't work, the db likely (though not guaranteed - it's corrupt, after all!) does not have the source for the stored procedure.

```
exec sp_helptext 'some_procedure`
```

Of course, the *correct* answer is: **restore from backup**.

Comment: Nope, this resulted in Msg 605, Level 21, State 3, Procedure parameters$, Line 2
Attempt to fetch logical page (1:56) in database 7 failed. It belongs to allocation unit 0 not to 281474980642816.